# why wont my @media query code be applied to tablets?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a problem with the `@media query` tag. I started working on a portfolio page and after finish the code for a mobile-width I went along to code the tablet-width version (and then later the desktop one) using media queries. Unfortunately, when I finished the tablet-width code and went on to check how the page looked I realized the same code is now applying to the phone-width too.
I'll show my code below.

Phone-width code:

```css
.grid {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "header header"
        "content content"
        "sidebar sidebar"
        "footer footer";
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

And now the tablet-width code:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .grid {
        width: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: 
            "header header"
            "content sidebar"
            "content article"
            "footer footer";
        grid-gap: 10px;
    }
}
```

Whatever source of info I find, they all show the code exactly the way mine was written, but still it fails to run. Hope I'm missing something so the process of fixing it turns out quick

Comment: What media query are you using for your phone-width code?

Comment: Also check your actual width on the device. Modern phone screens can be quite huge.